# How to interpolate variable into markdown codeblock in Pluto.jl?

Tags: julia, pluto.jl

In Pluto if I try to include an interpolated value in the markdown string, it renders the string without interpolating the value.
[image]

I'd like the string to render as: My variable's value is: `10`

Comment: Did you try to declare x =before= your md section ? Under this condition, interpolation works for me. (but you must use $x and not  '$x')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown itself isn't intended to interpolate variables. You may use `Markdown.parse` instead of `md""` literal. This allows the string to interpolate the variables before passing to the Markdown parser.

```
Markdown.parse("""
My variable's value is: `$x`.
""")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a little trouble combining this with math, which uses the `$` symbol as a delimiter.

One solution was to use [LaTeXStrings.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStrings/LaTeXStrings.jl)

```
using LaTeXStrings

L"""\text{My variable's value is } %$(x)"""
```

Using @Stepan Zakharov's approach

```
Markdown.parse("""My variable's value is \$x\$""")

Markdown.parse("""\$\\mu\$ and \$x\$""")
```

but I found odd line breaking behaviour this way.